# Can margin interest be added to a debit balance beyond 50% equity?

Tags: stocks, mutual-funds, brokerage, margin, margin-call

I carry a margin balance and I am always trying to plan ahead for the worst-case scenarios…

If I get below 50% equity in my mutual fund brokerage account because of market fluctuation and a margin balance, can the accruing margin interest continued to be added to the balance as is happening now?

I realize that I would not be able to buy more shares or borrow more money because I am below 50%, but can the debit balance continue to be increased by the interest charges down to the brokerage’s margin call minimum percentage? Or would I have to take actions to cover each month’s interest charges?

Is the answer to this question, a standard SEC policy or would it vary from broker to broker?

Comment: How are you paying interest now? Would make sense that if you don't add more cash to cover the interest payments they'd be added to the margin balance.

Comment: Currently, the accruing interest is just added to my margin/debit balance.

Comment: So... what's your question? Whether your balance can go down due to interest and trigger margin call? Yes.

Comment: That is not my question.

I am wondering if interest can continue to accumulate in the space below 50% equity, down to the margin call percentage? Or is that considered similar to buying more mutual funds or borrowing more money and adding interest to my margin balance when equity is below 50% would not be allowed?

Comment: Why wouldn't be allowed? Where else would it go? You can't *borrow* more money, but unless you pay the interest, it will be added to the balance, what else would happen to it?

Comment: Your statement is logical to me (and what I want the answer to be) but I just wanted to make sure that they would allow that verses requiring me to take an action each month to cover that month's interest.

Comment: Noone can force you to do anything. They can prevent you from taking more loans, but the interest accumulates without your action. They can make a margin call (and will) if you keep not paying, that's the only leverage they have.

Comment: Margin fees are debits and they reduce buying power, increasing the amount of margin you're on.  Margin requirements is set by the Fed. The only leeway that brokers have is to set more restrictive requirements.

Comment: OP: If you are concerned that accruing margin interest being added to your margin balance will force you to "take actions to cover each month’s interest charges" then you're focused on the wrong issue.  You are using too much margin.